# Старт файла после его перезаписи Python

Tags: python, файлы

Я создал программу которая обновляет файл, то-есть перезаписывает его и открывает но при запуске выполняется старая версия файла, при том если сделаю time.sleep на 10 сек перед выполнением файла, если посмотреть на него то все изменения уже есть, но выполняется старая версия.
Что делать ?
Код который изменяет файл

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from test import version
import time


r = requests.get('секрет')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')


for ver in html.select(".items > .version"):
  open("vers.txt", 'w').write(ver.text)
  if float(ver.text) != version:
    open('vers.txt', 'w').write(ver.text)
    for el in html.select(".items > .cod"):
      for trueor in html.select('.items > .yesorno'):
        if trueor.text == "no":
          for dop in html.select('.items > .dop'):
            a = open("test.py", 'r')
            b = a.read().replace(str(version), str(ver.text))
            b = b.replace("###", dop.text)
            print('no')
            with open('test.py', 'w') as f:
              f.write(b)
        if trueor.text == "yes":
          print('yes')
          with open('test.py', 'w') as f:
            f.write("version = " + ver.text + "\n\n" + el.text)
        if trueor.text != "no" and trueor.text != "yes":
          print("Ошибка обновления, напишите создателю.\nError: 'yes or no'")

time.sleep(1)
import test
test.gg()
```

Задачей было создать программу которая пере записывает файл а потом стартует его, то есть обновляет файл, берёт обновление с моего сайта.Тоесть я хотел делать программы которые мог обновлять через сайт, чтобы кому давал программы могли не каждый раз скачивать у меня новую версию, а могли просто открыть апдатер и обновить. Это всё. Я смог сделать только этот код.

Comment: Можно код, или более подробный вопрос?

Comment: А как вопрос по другому сделать не знаю, кратко вот это файл стартуется работает, работает, перезаписывает файл, запускает файл а запускается старая версия допустим до перезаписи файл выводил в cmd "Привет мир", а после перезаписи должен выводить "пока мир", а при старте после перезаписи (вот стартер ``` test.gg()``` и что над ним) , выводится "Привет мир" и только после повторного запуска "Пока мир"

Comment: В вашем коде два места где делается `import test`. Второй импорт ничего не делает, так как первый уже загрузил и скомпилировал код раньше.

Comment: Не храните данные внутри исполнимого кода. Храните данные внутри файлов данных. Исполнимый код неизменен. Данные изменяемы. Нарушать этот порядок можно, но надо понимать как работает система модулей Python.

Comment: Как вариант, вы можете ожидать дату изменения файла, когда она поменяется, тогда и открывайте файл. Чем больше будет файл и нагружена система, тем дольше нужно времени на запись(По факту это происходит моментально, актуально только для очень больших файлов)

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy, стоп как, не понимаю, если я запустил код то в любом случае будет исполняться код до изменения, типо файл изменяется а код берётся из прошлой версии ? А как значит после переписи просто выключить код чтобы он заново включился ?

Comment: И ещё если я хочу сделать этот код в exe то вызываемые объекты 'version' будут одинаковые или нет и как из exe получить код python и наоборот

Comment: @Georg вы этот код из exe так не импортируете, и не сохраните обратно в exe после изменения. Используйте форматы специально предназначенные для конфигов, и храните их вне exe файла.

Comment: Georg, добавляйте `@` если хотите чтобы я ответил на ваши сообщения. Python поддерживает кеш загруженных модулей. Если модуль однажды был загружен, его файл с диска больше не читается. Есть способы обойти это ограничение, но они не всегда работают. Если нужно загрузить новую версию модуля, лучше всего остановить завершить текущий интерпретатор и запустить новый, то есть запустить программу заново. Это сложно и накладно, поэтому я написал что держать меняющиеся данные в файлах с кодом - плохо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перезагрузить файл

```
from test import version
import test
import importlib

.....

importlib.reload(test)
version = test.version
```

Но в случае обновления программы я рекомендую перезапустить питона полностью.

```
import os,sys
print('Запуск')
if os.environ.get('NEEDUPDATE', 'YES') == 'YES':
    print('Код обновления')
    os.environ['NEEDUPDATE']='NO'
    os.execl(sys.executable, 'Имя проги в списке процессов' , *sys.argv)
print('Код программы')
```

Выведет

```
$ python3 execself.py 
Запуск
Код обновления
Запуск
Код программы
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146892/discussion-on-answer-by-eri------python); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.